# Science behind working of Pushpak Vimanam

Tags: ramayana

I don't know whether I should ask this in Hinduism or Physics but I think my question would would better relate with this site.

According to an ancient epic ***Ramayana***, *Ravana* was having an aircraft named '*Pushpak Vimanam*', which is believed to be one of the ancient miracles in Hinduism epic and advancement of technology at that time. Well I am currently in my academics in my final year and studying the detailed properties of charge and magnetism. My teacher told me that few theories have been made that *Pushpak Vimanam* might be working on this principal.

In detailed way his air craft must have been made with a light weight conductor which might be having charge uniformly distributed over it's surface leading to formation of some electric and magnetic field that may help in lifting the aircraft and balancing the gravitational force. However it still remains a mystery that how *Vimanam* was able to get such enormous charge.

At that age if technology was so much advanced then why not someone wrote the working and mechanism behind that like we study about some complex machines in high school today?

Beside this also I want to ask whether it can be true? Means are there any kind of evidence or anything which can prove this?

Comment: I had made an edit. I think you should re-read the question

Comment: [fairy dust](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fairydust)

Comment: Question regarding Science are off topic. [Related discussion](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/142/users-asking-for-scientific-answers-reasons?cb=1)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about scientific speculations

Comment: yes, I turned into a spiritual speculation instead in my answer :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Science behind religious things are off topic here. But to clarify certain things you mentioned in the question, I am answering your post.

I can't say about the science behind such an aircraft, but I can say that crafts like those were not completely mechanical. Modern scientists forget to take into account spiritual powers. There are two kinds of science, spiritual which is based upon the existence of spirit, and material, which is based upon the existence of subatomic particles. So such aircrafts must have made use of spiritual power through the usage of *mantra*, *yantra*, etc.

Now why no one wrote down the technology behind it could be because such aircrafts were not the norm like we see on airplanes today. Those were used by gods and didn't belong to earth. For example, Ravan got the airplane from Kubera (VRM - [6.121.9](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga121/yuddhasans121.htm#Verse9)), which was made by Viswakarma for Brahma. Similarly, there is another instance in the Bhagavatam where Śālva obtains such a fighter aircraft as a boon from Lord Shiva.

> The great Lord Umāpati is known as “he who is quickly
>   pleased,” yet only at the end of a year did he gratify Śālva, who had
>   approached him for shelter, by offering him a choice of benedictions. [SB - 10.76.5]
>
> Śālva chose a vehicle that could be destroyed by neither
>   demigods, demons, humans, Gandharvas, Uragas nor Rākṣasas, that could
>   travel anywhere he wished to go, and that would terrify the Vṛṣṇis.  [SB - 10.76.6]
>
> Lord Śiva said, “So be it.” On his order, Maya Dānava, who conquers his enemies’ cities, constructed a flying iron city named
>   Saubha and presented it to Śālva.  [SB - 10.76.57]
>
> This unassailable vehicle was filled with darkness and could go anywhere. Upon obtaining
>   it, Śālva went to Dvārakā, remembering the Vṛṣṇis’ enmity toward him. [SB - 10.76.8]

So **because those were divine objects and not a norm in the world, nobody probably wrote it down**. It is also another fact that retaining knowledge in memory was the norm in the ancient times rather than keeping a written record of it.

However, irrespective of its authenticity we do have a [Vaimanika Shastra](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vaim%C4%81nika_Sh%C4%81stra&oldid=611994428) written down in earlier part of the twentieth century. As per the writer, he obtained the knowledge from sage Bharadwaja. On a side note, it is worth noting that Shri Rama on his way to Ayodhya on the Pushpaka Vimana took a halt at Rishi Bharadwaja's hermitage. To be frank, whatever actual science was behind such crafts was probably known only to the gods and the sages. We modern day people can only speculate it must have been like this, it must have been like that, etc. without taking spiritual power into account.

Comment: Always quality and detailed answers

Comment: "Modern Scientists forget to take into account". They don't forget. They don't take into account because there is no proof, evidence or logic. I could point to any old witchcraft book and when asked for evidence I could say "It's magic".

Comment: If the scientists started remembering/considering everything every book says there would be no science. The fundemental rule of science is to observe, use common sense, acquire proof.

Comment: If you demonstrate proof of magic or spirit or whatever under lab conditions scientists would consider it.

Comment: The problem is there is no information or proof advanced knowledge that can be recreated. They claim they had flying machines. They don't present any mechanism of the machine to verify that. People all around the world were fascinated by flying machines and there are many references to flying machines even in fiction before modern aircrafts existed.

Comment: Even if a scientist takes into account the possibility of magic he'd be able to contribute nothing to the scientific society because he'd be unable to obtain any credible information on this "forbidden/elitist knowledge". He'd just be wasting his time.

Comment: Most science is based on knowing and understanding the mechanism. Sicentists mostly share their knowledge. If a scientist says, "I have built a machine that time travel machine. I won't show it to you. I won't explain it to you. But it is true". His peers will laugh it off.