# Pushpaka Vimana

Tags: scripture, ramayana

Rama travelled in Pushpaka Vimana to crown Vibhishana dn returned to Ayodhya in the same vimana. Any detailed information about this and how it functioned?

Comment: Probably This question already has an answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/769/science-behind-working-of-pushpak-vimanam

Comment: When I typed the question title it has not shown Duplicate. Hence I continued the body of the question and posted.