# Why do we not have the technology used by Ravana, or others in EPICs?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, ramayana

My questions are about all the supernatural weapons and things used.

If everything was oral tradition, I agree and respect that as well. Why isn't that available like Vedas and other things? You can forget about the events from Ramayan for a moment too as that was nearly 2.1 million years back, but what about Mahabharat which has technologies from few thousand years ago.

Some positive points, the remains of Idols found across India, Indonesia(Krishna Arjun), Thailand, Afghanistan, etc. The plastic surgery, cataract, etc. mentioned in the book Shusrut Samhita, etc.

However, regarding techonologies, please share your thoughts!

- Is there any recorded knowledge for how to invoke or use Brahmastra or other DIVINE weapons used in Ramayana or Mahabharata or any other scripture, if not, why wasn't that all recorded or known or passed on?
- I agree with Vimana Shastra, where it's written on how to make spacecrafts using what materials and what a pilot should do. But why isn't there a single human being making use of that book and creating something or understanding those things?
- Why does no one have any knowledge regarding those weapons, or levitating in skies with human body, etc.? How to prove that Yudhistihir's Chariot was actually levitating one feet above the ground at all times until the Mahabharat War?

Comment: are nuclear misslie launch codes known to everyone, or only a select few army personnel that have undergone rigorous training and have gained trust of nation's safeguarders ? similarly, advanced mantras and shastras can still be learned by intense penance and gaining trust of Vedas' safeguarders

Comment: You mean the use of supernatural weapons? As far as I know that knowledge is not there. Also, no other person in this current age or time has ever seen to be using a supernatural weapon. Maybe it is all just mythology.

Comment: @Wikash_, nobody on this website has seen you in person. Maybe you're just a robot on the internet.

Comment: @ram yes that is true. Then again you just also maybe an alogrithm. Also, my statements are based on facts so if I am a robot I am doing pretty good.

Comment: @Wikash_, Yes. Also, my statements are based on fact, so if I am human I am doing pretty good.

Comment: @ram If one wants to learn Nuclear Energy and the making of Nuclear missile, one knows what to study. There is evidence that it can be made, learn and taught. I am referring to books which mention or people who can teach these in the current time which provides evidence that this is possible and one can incite snakes, water, fire and other things like fly with one;s own chariot using mantras.

Comment: Too many questions? We might don't know ancient technology, they must have made use of spiritual power through the usage of mantra, yantra, etc.. Check this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/769/science-behind-working-of-pushpak-vimanam

Comment: @ram ", my statements are based on fact," well sorry this not the case in your situation. If you would be using facts I do not mind talking to a robot.

Comment: @Wikash_, you're not using facts. you're talking gibberish now.

Comment: @ram show me facts instead attacking me.

Comment: All of these are spiritual powers and mentioned in detail in Uddhava Gita by Krishna. Mankind is too much tamsik, undisciplined and short lived to understand and take these powers in current Kaliyuga, thats why science has come up so that mankind will start reasoning and try to think beyond mere animal instincts and senses, while spiritual siddhis are manifested materially by modern scientists, like doordarshan-doorshravan has become audio video transmission, vimana operating from mental powers is being operated with petrochemicals, and its all for facility of mankind.

Comment: Pollution from petrochemicals has harms but anyway mankind is shortlived and dumper and was killing each other in name of religions,race, kingdoms, temporary gold  and scriptures which they didnt really understand, prior to development of nuclear missiles and modern weapons. Fear of nuclear missiles and drop on Japan during WW2 brought peace to modern world, just like vocal invoked weapons were feared by people during Mahabharata .Child is not given a knife else he will cut himself or others, only wise men can handle it, similar are Siddhis & sound astras. Katapayadi System is Shabda Brahman.

Answer (score 2):

The questions are

> - Is there any recorded knowledge for how to incite or use ***Brahmastra or
>   its likes*** in Mahabharat or any other scripture, if not, why wasn't
>   that all recorded or known or passed on?
> - Why isn't that available ***like Vedas and other things***?
> - Why does no one have any knowledge regarding those weapons, or transcending in skies with human body, etc.?
> - I agree with Vimana Shastra, where it's written on how to make spacecrafts using what materials and what a pilot should do. But why isn't there a single human being making use of that book and creating something or understanding those things? Or is there anyone?

Good questions indeed.

---

Let me start with 2nd point first

1. The Veda, to be precise Rig, Yaju and Sama ( I am not taking Atharva into consideration into the core Veda Category) Vedas, contain SPIRITUAL matters, occasionally mentioning some historical facts like Daśarājñá yuddhá, about Manu, Bharata, etc.

It does not mean to say that The Veda do not refer to any weapons.  They do refer to Vajra of Indra, Parasu of Varuna, etc.  As the Veda contain multi-layered meanings, these weapons can be interpreted in different ways.

The same Vajra was mentioned in Ramayana and Mahabharata also.

---

2. The DIVINE weapons mentioned in Ramayana or Mahabhrata were not Nuclear as many would like to believe.  They are of different technology, which was not described in those EPICs.

Further, their usage also mentioned ***in different ways*** by different people.

a) Those DIVINE weapons were used either through **an arrow made of Iron or Kusa grass**, uttering some mantra.

- Sri Rama [used **brahmAstra**](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga38/sundara_38_frame.htm) against a crow, the son of Indra, through a blade of grass
- Aswatthama used **brahmashira**, through a blade of grass, against the descendants of Pandavas, which killed the unborn baby in the womb of Uttara.

b) Indrajit used brahmastra in 2 ways

- to catch hold of Sri Hanuman, who was found invincible ([Sundara kanda)](https://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga48/sundara_48_frame.htm)
- to eliminate 67 crores of vanaras in a single day

> सप्तषष्टिर्हताः कोट्यो वानराणां तरस्विनाम् | अह्नः पञ्चमशेषेण वल्लभेन
> स्वयम्भुवः || (Yuddha Kanda 74 Sarga 12 Sloka)
>
> ***Sixty seven crores*** of powerful monkeys were struck down by the
> cherished missile of Brahma, the self-born creator, in the fifth and
> last period of the day.

---

In all cases, if we observe closely, we will find that except the targetted people no one else got affected due to impact of that DIVINE weapon.

For example, when Indrajit used the brahmAstra, it affected Vanaras only, but not Rakshasas, who were also present in the war field.

---

Coming to the aspect of non-availability of those DIVINE weapons now, we have to remember that even in that era also, only a handful of few were described to be in possession of those weapons, but not all.

So to acquire those DIVINE weapons, rigorous training, practice, etc are needed.  When those qualities were not found in subsequent generations, they might have lost to the them.

Losing of knowledge in any field occurs not only in one field alone, but in many fields.

---

One accomplished Guru in Gayatri Mantra said once (Sri Paakalapati Guruvu - Telugu) that mere keeping of hands in a form and touching some parts of body and reciting mantra, does not assure Siddhi in Gayatri mantra.

It needs something else, which will be **made known to the eligible aspirants** by the NATURE/GOD directly, but not to all.

It is confidential knowledge.

That was why, he added, not many people were able to get the Siddhi in that Mantra.

---

Same is the case with DIVINE weapons.  Only the eligible ones will get the knowledge, but not by everyone.

Who is eligible, will be decided by the God alone.